# pass loop from view.py to html template in Django

Tags: django, django-queryset

I try to get the data in my models "Machines" and then need to get Additional information form other table related to each machine.
I try bellow code in views.py and render it to specified html page.

```
def allmachinesLOGO(request):
    machines=Machine.objects.all()
    c=""
    for m in machines:
        if m.tb_order_set.filter(status="2").exists():
            c="2"
        else:
            c="0"
    
    context ={'machines':machines,'condition':c}
    return render(request,'pline/machineslogos.html',context)
```

```
{% if condition == "2"  %}
            
                    <h4> working</h4>
                    <img class="btn-circle" style="width: 15px" src="{% static 'images/icons/icons8-green-circle-48.png' %}" alt="image" />
                  {% else %}
                      <h4>stop</h4>
                          {{ condition }}
                    <img class="btn-circle" style="width: 15px" src="{% static 'images/icons/icons8-red-circle-48.png' %}" alt="image" />
                    {% endif %}
```

what's the correct way to pass loop from views.py to template in Django

Comment: What exactly you want to display on template

Comment: hi i just want to show if the machine is working or not working by status filed from another table . if status =2 then is working if not then shows not working

Comment: in terminal when I print condition , its work fine but when I move html to check if is equal to "2" or not it always written 0

Comment: what is the value of this line `m.tb_order_set.filter(status="2").exists()` ?

Comment: its placed in for loop , for each entry in table , if statement check if a row with status=2 is exist or not , base on that it written true or false. so if its true then c is equal to 2 and if is not c=0

Comment: can you share `models`

Comment: @ashkan try to print on each iteration of the loop 'c' you have the last c = 0 most likely, so 0.

Comment: @ashkan added option to filter with one line: Machine.objects.filter(tb_order__status='2'). Also updated the template code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the view, at each iteration of the loop, I create a dictionary with two values: 'machines', 'status' and put it in the aaa list.

Either remove the line in the view(if you don't want the lines with 'status'= '0' to be displayed.):

```
else:
     aaa.append({'machines': m, 'status': '0'})
```

then the line with 'machines': m, 'status': '0' will not be recorded.

Perhaps there is a way without a cycle to filter by the secondary model. It would be interesting to see if there is such a way.

views.py

```
def allmachinesLOGO(request):
    machines = Machine.objects.all()
    aaa = []
    for m in machines:
        if m.tb_order_set.filter(status='2').exists():
            aaa.append({'machines': m, 'status': '2'})
        else:
            aaa.append({'machines': m, 'status': '0'})

    context = {'context': aaa}

    return render(request, 'pline/machineslogos.html', context)
```

templates

```
{% for m in context %}
{% if m.status == '2' %}
<h4> working</h4>
<p>{{ 'machines' }} : {{ m.machines }} {{ 'status' }} : {{ m.status }} </p>
{% else %}
<h4>stop</h4>
<p>{{ 'machines' }} : {{ m.machines }} {{ 'status' }} : {{ m.status }} </p>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

One more way. Filter Machine by secondary model with status='2'. To make sure this is the case, two loops (the outer one iterates over Machine, and the inner one a.tb_order_set.all() and outputs status to print(stat.status)):

```
bbb = Machine.objects.filter(tb_order__status='2')#If unique records are needed, then add distinct().
print(bbb)
for a in bbb:
  for stat in a.tb_order_set.all():
     print(stat.status)
```